# I want to figure out how many Topologies are in the set X

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, proof-writing

I have the set $$X = \{1, 2, 3\}$$

and I want to figure out how many different topologies I can get from the set $X$

so what I have done is assumed that the empty set and the whole set are in $T$

and that any union of elements will satisfy, $X \in T$, as well as any intersection of elements.

therefore all possibilities will be considered topologies.

so after I assume this, my answer I acheived was a simple $3!*3! + \emptyset = 37$.

Leading me to the fact that I believe there are 37 different topologies possibel from this set $X$.

Any help, disccrestions, criticims, or corrections would be great, i only have 75% confidence in this result.

thanks in advance

Comment: 29 distinct topologies over a set of 3 elements.

Comment: Your answer should be 29. How did you get $(3!)^2+1$? Maybe we can explain why you over-counted.

Comment: @Bryan I did this because of the ability to get equal amount of intersections and unions, and the 1 is to account for the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to count the open sets.
First, if $X$ is a set and $S\subseteq X$, then $\{\varnothing, S, X\}$ is a topology for $X$.
Also if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ then $\{\varnothing, A,A\cap B, B, X\}$ is a topology
for $X$.

Using the first fact, we can determine there are $7$ topologies over $X$ (this include $S=\varnothing$ or $S=X$).

Using the second fact we can count some more topologies. When one is a singleton and the other its complement, we count 3 topologies.

When one is a singleton, and other a doubleton which contains the singleton, we count 3 more.

When both are disjoint singletons, we get 3 topologies.

Next we can count 3 more topologies, by counting 2-element sets which share 1 element.

You can see how to count the rest by considering $\{\varnothing, A,B,C,A\cap B,A\cap C,etc.,\dots, X\}$