# How do we find the 26 topologies on the set X = {a,b,c}

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I want to know an easy to justify logical method of finding the topologies or at least to show that there are 26 topologies on the set. Will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What's wrong with just listing them, one by one?

Comment: Think first about the two subsets that are open in every topology, and think next about a systematic way to organize and count all the ways to have more open sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652354/391136

Comment: Have you tried counting the possible topologies of a 2-element set? If not, that wouldbe a helpful warmup. (There are only 4.)

Comment: There are in fact 29 topologies, 9 if we only count non-homeomorphic ones. See [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2000&task=show_msg&msg=0041.0001) for a list. And I reproduced it [on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3347582/4280) too.